# Set some class object to Local Storage

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

I'm using Angular CLI. Actually, I have registration component:
ts

```
...
export class User {
  first_name: string;
  second_name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
...
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  saveValue(storageValue) {
  localStorage.setItem(`user`, new User(storageValue.first_name, storageValue.second_name));
```

html

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" [(ngModel)]="first_name">
<input type="text" name="second_name" [(ngModel)]="second_name">
```

So I'm trying to set User object to Local storage but there is an error:  *Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.*
I have tryed yet:

```
...
saveValue(storageValue) {
      localStorage.setItem(`user`, new User(String(storageValue.first_name), String(storageValue.second_name));
...
```

and

```
...
saveValue(storageValue) {
      localStorage.setItem(`user`, JSON.stringify(new User(storageValue.first_name, storageValue.second_name));
..
```

however, it doesn't work. Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only set a string to local storage, so you need to figure out a way to serialize/deserialize your `User` object.

**Serialize**

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({
  first_name: storageValue.first_name,
  second_name: storageValue.second_name
}));
```

**Deserialize**

```
const raw = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
const user = new User(raw.first_name, raw.second_name);
```

Comment: Thanks helped a lot